# How can I make this String counter code more efficient?

Tags: java, performance

Here is my code.
Method `counter` counts the number of times each alphabet occurs in the string.

public class Hard{

```
public static void counter (String s) {

  for (int n = 0; n < s.length() ; n++) {

       int count = 0 ,bool = 1;

       if (n > 0) {  

          for (int L = n-1 ; L >= 0  ; L--) {
             if (s.charAt(n) == s.charAt(L)) {bool = 0; }         
          }

       }

       for (int f = 0; f < s.length() ; f++ ) {
         if (bool == 0) { break ; }

         if (s.charAt(n) == s.charAt(f)) {count++;}
       }

       if (count > 0 ) {

         System.out.println(s.charAt(n)+" appears "+count+" times.");
       }
  }
```

}

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
   counter("bbaddadxzxwfgb$.fgfdf");                  
 }
```

}

Comment: Is this Java/C#? Format your code to look clearer/indented please

Comment: Yes, please include a tag with your language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Java and assuming A and a are counted as the same letter.

```
public static int[] counter (String s) {
    int [] countArr = new int[26];
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        char charAtI = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(charAtI)) {
            countArr[Character.isUpperCase(charAtI) ? charAtI - 'A' : charAtI - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    return countArr;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int [] countArr = counter("asif and abid.");
    for(int i = 0; i<countArr.length; i++) {
        if(countArr[i] > 0) {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} appears {1} times", (char)(i + 'a'), countArr[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

The key to the optimization lies in the fact that it performs *one* pass with no nested loops and once you have all the information you require, then worry about how to present it to the user.

Comment: Combining Unicode-aware `Character.isLetter` with ASCII-only `charAtI - 'A'` is a terrible idea. I wouldn't mind code dealing with ASCII only, but this one blows whenever it sees any non-ASCII letter.

Comment: I'm going for efficiency, not robustness.  If we're counting every character available in unicode, this is not going to be the solution for you.  However the op didn't even seem to care about uppercase letters, which this solution still takes into consideraiton.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static HashMap<Character, Integer> counter(String input) {

    HashMap<Character, Integer> chCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0 i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (chCount.containsKey(c)) {
        int count = chCount.get(c);
        chCount.put(c, count + 1);
        } else {
        chCount.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    return chCount;
    }
```

You can use hashmaps as well. It will work for other characters like '#', etc and you can treat 'A' and 'a' differently, because the key value will be different. 
[HashMap tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm)

Comment: More robust than the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can count chars like this, using **java 8**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String string="what is this?";
        List<Character> chars=string.chars().distinct().mapToObj(i->Character.valueOf((char)i)).filter(p->Character.isAlphabetic(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        chars.forEach(c->{
        long count=string.chars().mapToObj(i->Character.valueOf((char)i)).filter(p->p==c).count();
        System.out.println(c+" appear "+count+" times");
        });
 }
```